# Wordpress login page blank after customizations - works on other sites

Tags: login

I did some modifications to the wp-login.php, which worked fine on 2 testsites. They run higher version of php, i think both run php 7. The main site runs php 5.4 or something around it. On the main site as soon as i upload the child theme, then wp-login.php page simply goes blank.

It might be important to say, that everything else on the site show except the wp-login.php
I believe it might be the low PHP version, but i'm not sure.

These are the codes:

```
function my_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/login_styles.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_stylesheet' );

function my_login_logo() { ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
    background-image: url(../wp-content/uploads/2017/08/login_logo.png);
    height: 125px;
    width: auto;
    background-size: 125px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
<?php }
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'my_login_logo' );

function my_login_logo_url() {
    return home_url();
}
add_filter( 'login_headerurl', 'my_login_logo_url' );

function my_login_logo_url_title() {
    return '';
}
add_filter( 'login_headertitle', 'my_login_logo_url_title' );
```

How come it doesn't work?

Comment: Did you modify a core file? In that case, I suggest you immediately revert the changes, and then ask a question about how to it without modifying the core. I would be happy to help in that case.

Comment: Looking at the provided code he modified the file properly through hooks, so I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `WP_DEBUG` in your WordPress to get current error.

Set it on the wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```